# Running DOSBox completely headless

Tags: dosbox

I have an old compiler written for DOS that I need to be able to use on a modern Linux system.  I have written a wrapper around DOSBox that allows me to invoke it from a Linux command line.

The only problem is that DOSBox does not seem to have an option to suppress the main emulator window that pops up while it is running.  It does not hinder the program's functionality (I have the output piped to a file), but I would like to be able to run DOSBox without the emulator window appearing.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DOSBox uses SDL, which can be told to use a different display driver by setting the environment variable `SDL_VIDEODRIVER`.  The `dummy` driver will display nothing at all, not even a window.

On Unix, use the `export` shell command:

```
export SDL_VIDEODRIVER=dummy
```

and on Windows, use `set`.

```
set SDL_VIDEODRIVER=dummy
```

Note that on Windows, you will need to use `-noconsole` to prevent DOSBox from generating the status terminal window.

Source:  [this forum post](http://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?t=22813).