# how to run DOSBox in command line without opening it in a new window

Tags: ms-dos, emulation, 16-bit, dosbox

how to run `DOSBox` using the default windows command line, (without opening it in a new window),
editing the source code of `DOSBox` is a solution, but i want to know if there is no other solution before rebuilding `DOSBox`.

else

is there any other application that can run 16 bit command line application in `CMD`.

i tried `DOSBox.exe -nonconsole` but it is not what i am searching for.
tried `ScummVM` and `D-Box` without results.

Comment: For an app to run 16-bit command line EXEs on x64 Windows *in cmd*, it would have to run the app, capture the output and redirect it somehow to cmd. I don't see the point. Use x86 Windows instead if it *has* to be run via cmd.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running DOSBox completely headless](https://superuser.com/questions/790519/running-dosbox-completely-headless)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know whether the answer will serve you. At least, I found it is possible to start DOSBox, execute commands, and exit it. This allows me to run automated tests on DOSBox via Travis CI. There will still be a window though, and it does not propagate an exit code to the caller.

The command would be as follows:

```
dosbox exit -c [your_command_here] >>log.txt" -noconsole -exit
```

For this to work, you have to have a file called `exit` in the current directory (because `exit` is run last, and expected to be an external command).

I use `log.txt` to get feedback from the Dos program.

To my knowledge, it is not possible to run DOSBox without a window. It would be nice if it returned the exit code of its command shell. This should be easy to implement, I think, but would require a source change.

I can't upvote yet but I do think this is a useful question, as DOSBox can be used for testing in a 16-bit environment. In that sense, the question would be suitable for StackOverlow, actually.

Answer (score 0):

[DOSEMU](http://dosemu.sourceforge.net/) can do this in its so-called [dumb mode](http://dosemu.sourceforge.net/docs/README/1.4/x724.html), e.g.

```
dosemu -dumb DIR
```

Note that there is now also an unstable [DOSEMU 2](https://github.com/dosemu2/dosemu2). It is not clear to me if this is a continuation or a fork.

Comment: More about DOSEMU history & how it fits with FreeDOS here: https://archive.fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/dosemu_and_freedos_past_present_future/attachments/slides/2466/export/events/attachments/dosemu_and_freedos_past_present_future/slides/2466/dosemu_freedos.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use NTVDMx64 for this [http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/ntvdmx64.html](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eem36/ntvdmx64.html)

NTVDM is the NT Virtual DOS Machine subsystem which was part of 32-bit versions of Windows. It was able to run 16-bit MS-DOS programs using the V86 mode of the CPU. This mode however can't be used when the CPU is running in 64-bit mode. But luckily Microsoft had a version of NTVDM that used an emulator instead of V86 mode. This version was leaked and the above link has information on how to use it.